# Prove that the first eigenvector is an optimal solution to the optimization problem:

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

$A \in \mathbb{R}^{d \times d}$ is symmetric and positive semidefinite with eigenvalues $\lambda_1 > ... > \lambda_d$ and corresponding set of orthonormal eigenvectors $u^1, u^2, ..., u^d \in \mathbb{R}^d$. Prove that $u^1$ solves:

$\max_{w \in \mathbb{R}^d: ||w||_2 = 1} w^TAw$

Comment: Any $w \in \mathbb{R}^d$ can be written as a linear combination of the orthonormal eigenvectors. Use this to rewrite $w^\top A w$. And I guess your $u^1$ should be $e^1$.

Comment: That's the part I don't understand. How I would rewrite $w^TAw$ in terms of the eigenvalues given?

Answer (score 1):

You may use the spectral theorem to rewrite $A$ as $Q \lambda Q^T$ where $Q$ is orthonormal and $\lambda$ is diagonal made up of $\lambda_1, ... , \lambda_d$. You can then rewrite your objective as $w^T Q \lambda Q^T w = || \sqrt{\lambda} Q^T w||^2$, or with a change of coordinates $x = Q^Tw$, you get the objective $||\sqrt{\lambda} x||^2 = \sum \lambda_i x_i^2$ which is maximized with $x_1 = 1$ and the others equal to zero.

If you do not have "access" to the spectral theorem, you can use Lagrange multipliers. I think you should arrive at the equation $c w_{opt} = A w_{opt}$ for some constant c, which is nothing but the definition of an eigenvector. Knowing that the optimal input must be an eigenvector, then it follows that you can't beat an eigenvector $v$ the largest eigenvalue and of norm 1 which yields $v A v^T  = v \lambda_1 v^T  = \lambda_1 ||v||^2 = \lambda_1.$

Comment: How do you get from $x_1 = 1$ to saying that $u^1$ solves the optimization problem?

Comment: $x_1 = 1$ is shorthand for saying $x_1 = 1, x_2 = 0, ... , x_d = 0$ which is shorthand for saying that $x = (1, 0, ..., 0)^T$ but remember that $x = Q^T w = Q^{-1}w$ i.e. $Qx = w$. Hence $w$ is the first column of $Q$ which is known to be $u^1$

Comment: To see that the first column of $Q$ is $u^1$, you can check $Q\lambda Q^T (Q e_1) = Q\lambda (Q^T Q) e_1 = Q \lambda e_1 = Q \lambda_1 e_1 = \lambda_1 Q e_1$. Hence $Q e_1$ is an eigenvector with eigenvalue $\lambda_1$

Answer (score 1):

Every $w$ with $\|w\|_2=1$ can be written as $c_1 u^1 + \cdots + c_d u^d$ for some scalars $c_1, \ldots, c_d$ satisfying $c_1^2 + \cdots + c_d^2 = 1$.

Then
$$w^\top A w = \sum_{i,j} (c_i c_j)((u^i)^\top A u^j) = \sum_{i,j} (c_i c_j)\lambda_j ((u^i)^\top u^j) = \sum_j c_j^2 \lambda_j.$$
How would you choose $c_1, \ldots, c_d$ to maximize the right-hand side under the constraint $c_1^2 + \cdots + c_d^2=1$?